# how to put javascript timer code in another javascript file

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a set of questions that a user can access by logging in from drop down menu.  When user picks any question from the dropdown, I check if user is logged in or not by including a PHP file in case somebody adds it to their favorites and try to access without logging in later.

I also have a 15 minute countdown timer which works with the clock if user doesn't click calculate button atleast once every 15 consecutive minutes just like a screen saver or else user gets logged out.

Everything is working file as long as I have function timer() locally in the file, which means if I have 10 question, I have to copy and paste the same code 10 times in each file PLUS if I want to increase or decrease timer interval at a later date, I would have to modify each file individually.  So having a separate timer.js and calling a function timeout() from that file will be more effective and professional.
Lets say if all questions are in current directory.

I tried 2 unsuccessful ways,

1  include("timer.js")

2 <script style = "text/javascript" src = "timer.js"</script

(my syntax in #2 is correct, this website didn't let me put in script tags)

Using above two methods code just dumps above my menu, something for sure wrong.  How do I call the function timeout() from timer.js so it is common to all the questions.

Comment: Everything included in the script tag should be accessible anywhere in any other js file. There is something you are not showing or some framework specific limitation.

Comment: Unrelated: You can post a code snippet by adding 4 spaces before each line. Your script tag will be intact if you post it that way. If you want to have a code snippet in the middle of a sentence, you can surround the word with backticks. You'll get something like `this`